# Scaling the regex backreference

Tags: php, regex

I need to convert a font-size pt value to a font-size px value.  Since I have a 96dpi screen I need to scale up the pt value by 1.33 so that the px value has the same size on the screen as the pt value.  So far I have

```
$pattern = "/(\d+)pt/";
$replacement = "$1px"; 
$data = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $data);
```

But this just replaces 'pt' with 'px'. The replacement line needs to be something like  $replacement = "(1.33*$1)px";

How can I do this?

Comment: look at `preg_replace_callback`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`preg_replace_callback` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

```
$data = "5pt";
$pattern = "~(\d+)pt~";
$data = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($m) {
    return 1.33*$m[1]."px";
}, $data);
echo $data;
```

Output:

```
6.65px
```